# LINQ method syntax style

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, coding-style

I find that every programmer on our team writes LINQ queries completely different and sometimes it can be very difficult to read.  It is also very ugly to see these vastly varying styles in code (especially when existing in the same class).

Consider the following statement:

```
ActiveSiteEmployeesDropDownList.DataSource =
    CurrentCompany
        .Employees
        .Where(e => e.IsActive && e.Location == location)
        .Select(e => new
        {
            DisplayName = String.Format("{0}, {1}", e.Surname, e.FirstName),
            EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
        })
        .OrderBy(x => x.DisplayName);
```

What is your suggestion for how the above *should* be written?

Comment: I would write something very similar to that...

Comment: I find that very easy to read. I'd probably write it like that too.

Comment: I would write it exactly like that, perhaps moving the `{` on the same line with `new`.

Comment: Could you post some more examples from your project? What exactly is the problem with styling of that code?

Comment: Just what do you find confusing with that syntax / style?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Do you also keep your brace on the same line as the method declaration?  In that case, I would do the same for consistency sake.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I don't agree with that, that's not really C# style. It would only be correct if you write opening brace in the same line at all code blocks.

Comment: @davenewza Correct, I do keep `{` on the same line with method declarations and statements controlled by keywords (conditionals, loops, switches, and so on).

Comment: @FedorHajdu That's the brace placement style adopted at our company.

Comment: I would replace 'e' with 'x'. Why? Because 'e' is generally associated with EventArgs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like the way you wrote your query.

I would write it exactly the same way, except for the first line:

```
ActiveSiteEmployeesDropDownList.DataSource = CurrentCompany
    .Employees
    .Where(e => e.IsActive && e.Location == location)
    .Select(e => new
        {
            DisplayName = String.Format("{0}, {1}", e.Surname, e.FirstName),
            EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
        })
    .OrderBy(x => x.DisplayName);
```

I've also added some space for the anonymous object initialization.